# Установка нескольких стилей для элемента

Tags: wpf, c#

```
Ситуация следующая: имеется общий стиль для элементов Hyperlink

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#00FFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#00FF00"/>
                <Setter  Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

и несколько отдельных стилей, реализующих триггеры.

```
 <Style  x:Key="style1">
    <Setter  Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Property}" Value="Value1">
              <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
          </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Получается необходимо установить для определенного Hyperlink несколько стилей одновременно.

Подскажите, можно ли стандартными средствами wpf установить для элемента несколько стилей?

Answer (score 3):

Есть подобный вопрос на [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096/how-to-apply-multiple-styles-in-wpf)

Если коротко, то вы не можете использовать несколько стилей, но можете порождать каждый последующий стиль от предыдущего используя BasedOn.